# Android Google APIs GPS Data mocking not working in emulator?

Tags: android, gps

I want to mock GPS data in my emaulator. the application target is Google APIs 2.3.1, API level 9.

I tried sending location manually from DDMS, loading gpx files and sending from the emulator console but nothing happens.

can anybody provide me with detailed and tested steps to achieve the mocking ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it,

it's a bug in sdk 2.3, when I changed the target to sdk 2.1 it worked just fine